# How does Spell-Eating compare to Energy Drain?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, homebrew-review, monster-design

I'd like to replace the standard Energy Drain effect on a few CR3 Wights with the following Spell-Eater effect:

> **Spell-Eater**
>   On a successful Melee attack, the target must make a Will save against a DC equal to 10 + 1/2 the spell-eating creature’s racial HD + the spell-eating creature’s Cha modifier. (Same as Energy Drain). If the target fails the save, one of the following happens:
>
> 1. If they cast spells spontaneously: they lose one of their highest remaining spell slots and the spell-eating creature gains 5 temporary hitpoints (lasting 1 hour)
> 2. If they prepare spells: they lose a randomly selected spell from their highest spell slots and the spell-eating creature gains 5 temporary hitpoints (lasting 1 hour)
> 3. If they are not a caster, or only have 0th level spells remaining: nothing happens

The goal is to make the creature scarier to casters and less concerning to mundane characters, especially in a campaign where the party can't have a 15 minute adventuring day.

Thus my question is: How does this ability compare to Energy Drain and would it change the CR of a wight? (Bonus question: In general how valuable would this ability be if you were to fold it into the Monster Creation guidelines, so other users could add it to their own monsters?)

Answer (score 2):

### Introduction

I would say that this change makes the wights noticeably less of a threat, possibly to the point of making them CR 2 rather than CR 3. There are two questions to consider here...

### How Powerful is Energy Drain?

Compare [Wights](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/wight/) to [other CR 3 monsters](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/bestiary-by-challenge-rating/bestiary-cr-3-4) that are mostly physical threats like [Black Bears](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/bear/black-bear), [Medium Fire Elementals](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/elemental/elemental-fire/medium-fire-elemental), and [Dire Hyenas](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/hyena/hyena-dire). Notice how the others have a higher chance to hit and deal more damage when they do. This suggests that Energy Drain is a significant part of a wight's CR rating.

### How Powerful is Spell-Eater?

Spell-Eater is certainly not an insignificant ability, but I don't think it compares to Energy Drain. Here are a few reasons:

- It only affects spell casters; Energy Drain affects everyone.
- Losing a high-level spell slot hurts, but a negative level gives you a -1 at almost everything. Even as a caster, I might rather lose one spell than have my caster level reduced across the board.
- Many casters have other options besides casting spells. For example, clerics have channel energy and domain powers, witches have hexes, and wizards have school powers.
- Spell-Eater can't kill anyone, whereas enough negative levels will.
- It's easier to remove - simply resting restores spells (even if you have long adventuring days), whereas negative levels can persist for days.

Also, a wight has a 30 ft. speed and no special movement abilities. A wight isn't that likely to actually get in range to hit a caster. Level 4+ rangers and paladins will be on the front line, but losing a spell shouldn't bother them much. Wights do have high Stealth and an Int high enough to use it effectively, though, so it depends a bit on the circumstances.